# how to Use OAuth To Ask For Scope Permissions Immediately After Merchants adds your shopify app?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I got this reply from the Shopify review team with rejection of app. as I am new to Shopify and am not able to understand this issue.

is there anything am missing out ?
what i know is every access token comes with its respective scopes defined let me know if someone can help me into tackling this situation.
any help will be appreciated.

i tried reading out on community and i got this
[here i got this after search but didnt understood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glx3P.png)